# enable visualization in listbox windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, virtualization

am trying to show high quality images in phone ,as my image's size is too large app shows memory warning exception. so i tried visualization .but every time the listbox loads it loads whole data

xaml code:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ImageStack"

                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"    
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"     
           VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                   >
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></VirtualizingStackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.Resources>

                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding bimage}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding impath}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
```

and i used an IList

```
ImageStack.ItemsSource = new VirtualSongList();
```

and inside virtualsonglist class

```
 object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            // here is where the magic happens, create/load your data on the fly.
           // Debug.WriteLine("Requsted item " + index.ToString());

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(index.ToString());
            return new im { impath = "yyyyyyyyy", bimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/c"+index+".png", UriKind.Relative)) };
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

can anyone suggest a efficient way to display high quality image galley in windows

Comment: I think you should use the longlistselector instead. Eventhough it hs some issues, this will enable you to have some more data, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Use LongListSelector that was built with Virtualization in mind. 
Even in that case it might not solve your problem if you are being too aggressive with your image memory. 
Since you have limited space in your WP screen try making and showing a thumbnail of your image instead at first using BitmapImage::DecodePixelHeight and BitmapImage::DecodePixelWidth instead of decoding the full thing and therefore storing the full thing in memory. You can still show the full size image inside a details page, one at a time, when the user selects to do so. 
Also try experimenting with BitmapImage::CacheOption (or other caching techniques) to see how you can better keep your memory in check.